# Is there a way to auto-format text with out using the Style class directly;

Tags: string, text, itext, itext7

```
String test = "Hello -this is a string of text";
```

Something like this:...
Whenever that string of text was used in an  itext 7 `Text` or `Paragraph` it would make `"this"` *italic* or some set up `Style`.

Pretty much use special characters to make `Text` appear with a certain `Style` using itext7:

I need something like this because, users of the program will want to make certain words *italic*.

The users type into a `TextArea` to define a `String`.
I have strings saved, then just make a `Text` or `Paragraph` to hold that string:

```
            Cell location = new Cell()
                    .add(new Paragraph(test);
```

I though about using a `TextFlow` but that will not work with itext7 as it uses JavafX CSS.

Comment: Split you string into parts, create a `Text` object for each part, for the parts you want to change the style for set the corresponding style to the corresponding `Text` object, and then just add all the `Text` object to your paragraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this, it works but is not that pretty...

```
private Paragraph formatText(String string) {

    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();

        Stream.of(string)
            .map(w -> w.split(" "))
            .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
            .forEach(w -> {
                Text word;

                if (w.startsWith("~")) {
                    String replace = w.replace("~", "");
                    word = new Text(replace);
                    word.setItalic();   

                } else if (w.startsWith("*")) {                 
                    String replace = w.replace("*", "");
                    word = new Text(replace);
                    word.setItalic();       

                } else {                    
                    word = new Text(w);
                }

                paragraph.add(word);                    
            });

    return paragraph;

}
```